# Determine whether $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble determining whether $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ converges or diverges.

My first thought was to do the substitution $u=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ which algebraically could gives me something meaningful. But the problem I face with this substitution is that my integration boundaries become $u:0\rightarrow 0$ and such an integral is always 0, right? I'm not sure on that one. Would love some guidance.

Comment: Try writing it as $\int_0^{1/2}+ \int_{1/2}^{1}$ and using direct comparison test on each integral.

Comment: You can use the substitution $x=\sin^2\theta$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783173/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3191401/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853673/42969

Comment: The following is probably not what your instructor wants at this point, but this can be answered immediately from general principles that one should eventually pick up -- $\int_0^b \frac{1}{x^p}dx$ converges if $p < 1$ and diverges if $p \geq 1.$ In your case, both singularities correspond to $p = \frac{1}{2}$ (one being a $p = \frac{1}{2}$ singularity translated to $x=1),$ so we have convergence at each, and hence convergence on $[0,1].$ A similar analysis can be used for integrals over infinite domains, although for those we have convergence if $p > 1$ and divergence if $p \leq 1.$

Comment: Incidentally, the integral convergence-divergence behavior of $\frac{1}{x^p}$ "in the vicinity of $x=0$" can be converted to the integral convergence-divergence behavior of $\frac{1}{x^p}$ "in the vicinity of $x=\infty$", and vice-versa, by considering the area bounded by $y = \frac{1}{x^p}$ in two ways -- integration with respect to $x$ that corresponds to (the limit of) sums of the areas of horizontally-thin vertically oriented rectangles, and integration with respect to $y$ that corresponds to (the limit) of sums of the areas of vertically-thin horizontally oriented rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Ninad Munshi** have said :
try using $x=\sin ^{2} \theta$ as substitution to solve the integral,
or allow me to solve it for you using another way also :

Take the integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) x}} d x
$$
Factor powers:
$$
=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x} \sqrt{x}} d x
$$
For the integrand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x} \sqrt{x}}$,

substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $d u=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} d x$ :
$$
=2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}} d u
$$
The integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}$ is $\sin ^{-1}(u)$ : $=2 \sin ^{-1}(u)+$ constant

Substitute back for $u=\sqrt{x}$ :
$$
=2 \sin ^{-1}(\sqrt{x})+\text { constant }
$$
Which is equivalent for restricted $x$ values to:
Answer:
$$
=-2 \sin ^{-1}(\sqrt{1-x})+\text { constant }
$$
Then evaluate it from 0 to 1 to get : $\pi$, the least-known constant in mathematics.

As a plus, I want to add why your substitution didn't work, a remark that no one did comment on it here or gave an answer why it didn't work:

It's because your substitution is not increasing only(or decreasing only) between 0 and 1, and that's an important condition for doing u-sub.

Comment: Welcome. By the way, when dealing with letters in MathJax, you can use backslashes - indeed, you can use backslashes for almost anything. E.g., `$\pi,\omega,\theta$` will render as $\pi,\omega,\theta$, which is better than Unicode characters

Comment: It is _very_ hard — I would say impossible — to tell 'by eye' from looking at a graph whether an improper integral converges or diverges. Your second method is reasonable, but the first is hogwash.

Comment: @FShrike: Indeed it's more beautiful, thanks

Comment: @StevenStadnicki : You're absolutely right, but I tried to give like a "visual" representation (slightly intuitive) why it converges.

Comment: I would double down on @StevenStadnicki comment and push back that a "visual" representation is misleading and dangerous. The rate at which you go to infinity is very important. Take $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt x} = 2$, but looking at the graph near 0, it looks like $1/\sqrt x$ is diverging.

Comment: @Gregory, hmm I see, I shall edit then my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about convergence and not evaluating the integral, we can bound the integral directly.  More precisely,

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}+\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}.
$$
Using the substitution $u=1-x$ on the second integral, we get that this simplifies to
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}+\int_{1/2}^{0}\frac{-du}{\sqrt{(1-u)u}}=2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}.
$$
Now, we break the square root into two factors: $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}$.  Over the region of interest, $1-x$ varies between $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, so the smallest $\sqrt{1-x}$ could be is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Therefore,
$$
2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\leq 2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{2}\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\int_b^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
This integral is straight-forward to integrate as
$$
2\sqrt{2}\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\int_b^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{2}\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\left.2\sqrt{x}\right|_{b}^{1/2}=2\sqrt{2}\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}-2\sqrt{b}\right)=4.
$$
Since we have shown that this integral is less than a constant and the integrand is positive everywhere, the integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\b}{\mathcal{B}}$Cheating slightly, we can re-express the integral as:

$$\int_0^1x^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\d x=\b\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Where $\b$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), which satisfies for positive $x,y$ the relation:

$$\b(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Then your integral is:

$$\frac{(\Gamma(1/2))^2}{\Gamma(1)}=\pi$$

But maybe you are not familiar with this. I leave these for further reading.

Let's more elementarily evaluate this:

> Insert $x=\sin^2u$ to find: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2x}\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\d x=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}\d x=2\int_0^{\pi/2}1\d x=\pi$$

These substitutions are ok for the interval $(0,\pi/2)$, and what's more, if you use the $\epsilon-\delta$ idea of evaluating this integral on $(\epsilon,1-\delta)$, you can use these substitutions to see that the integral is convergent, so the fact that division by $\sin 0,\cos\pi/2$ features doesn't matter:

> Let $\epsilon,\delta\in(0,0.5)$ be fixed. $$\int_\epsilon^{1-\delta}x^{-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\d x=\int_{\arcsin\sqrt{\epsilon}}^{\arcsin\sqrt{1-\delta}}2\d x=2(\arcsin\sqrt{1-\delta}-\arcsin\epsilon)$$
>
> Independently of how $\epsilon,\delta\to0^+$, we see, by continuity of $\arcsin,\sqrt{}$ in these domains, that we get $2\arcsin 1=\pi$. Since this result is independent of the path/rate of approach, the integral is convergent and equal to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using $$x-x^2=\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2,$$ the integral is
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2}}dx$$
$$=\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{x-\frac12}{\frac12}\right)\right]^1_0$$
$$=\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

use $y=x-\frac12$, then:
$$
I=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt {x(1-x)}}dx=\int^\frac12_{-\frac12}\frac1{\sqrt {\frac14-y^2} }dy
$$
Subtituting $2y=\sin u$ we get:
$$
I=\int^\frac\pi2_{-\frac\pi2}du=\pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the range $[0,1]$ we have

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \sim \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{3 x^{3/2}}{8}+O\left(x^{5/2}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

Whence the convergence of the integral.
For the exact result, you can check for any answer here around.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{=2\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
\\\le 
2\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x\frac{1}{2}}}
\\=
2\sqrt 2\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
\\=4
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

So let's just solve for the primitive function
$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=2\int_0^1\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}
=2\arcsin\sqrt{x}\Big|_0^1=2(\arcsin1-\arcsin0)=\pi$